# Will having used one previous double-entry visa for China make me eligible for a multiple entry visa now?

Tags: visas, regulations, china, multiple-entry

China has a rule that to obtain a multiple entry visa you must be able to show immigration information for two previous stays, not always in very clear English.

Now just over a year ago in late 2013 and early 2014 I visited China two times on a double-entry visa that I obtained in Laos [after asking a previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19241/can-a-normal-backpacker-obtain-a-multiple-entry-chinese-visa-while-on-the-road) on the site about Chinese multiple-entry visas.

This time I have a narrower question. I intend to visit China again in just over a month and would really like a true multiple-entry visa this time so that I can cross over land borders into China's neighbours and back more times (I don't have an exact plan).

So will my two previous visits on a single two-entry visa satisfy this condition, or must it definitely be two physically separate visas?

Comment: Whether or not you can provide the necessary paperwork and proof, you might not be able to obtain a multiple-entry visa for China, depending on where you apply. As an Australian citizen I've found I can't get a true multiple entry visa in either Vietnam or Laos, though I can get a double-entry visa in Laos. Here's a new question just on where you can get true multiple-entry visas: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48052

Answer (score 3):

To apply for a six month multiple entry visa, you need to have previously had (and used) either two single entry visa or one double entry visa.  In order to apply for a one year multiple entry visa, you need to have previously had a six month multiple entry visa.

These are the rules for US citizens, but I imagine the qualification aspects would be the same for your nationality.

Comment: Now this sounds promising! Do you have some kind of reference I can check?

Comment: Same exact rules apply for airline crews (Crew Visa) as well!

Comment: Sure drop by my office and you can look at the information we have on file ;-)  Most of my answers are based on knowledge and experience not web searches.  But a quick Google for multiple entry china visas turned up this webpage which confirms my answer also applies to UK citizens - http://www.visaforchina.org.uk/faqs.php

Comment: This information is not correct for US citizens; they can get a 12 month, multiple entry L (tourism) visa without needing to have previously held any other visas. I did so in 2011, without any sort of assistance (simply filed the application at the consulate and checked the box for 1Y/ME), and there are plenty of similar reports on travel/expat forums. It is now possible to get *10 year* tourism visas; no prior visas required. Again, this applies to US citizens only. See [the official website](http://www.china-embassy.org/eng/visas/hrsq/).

Comment: The last time I applied (2014) they asked for that, but not an issue as I have several previous Chinese visas.  And there is nothing in your link that says otherwise. But as the OP is not a US citizen it is all moot anyway.  BTW welcome to Travel.

Comment: Is there something I need to show them or do they just check their records? I have a new passport since my previous trips to China and did not bring my old passport. I can probably find the dates of my previous entries and exits though.

Comment: I understood it to be they wanted to see them.  Never asked if they would look up old ones.  Best bet is to ask office you plan to apply at.

Answer (score 2):

**Maybe**. But this might not be all that's needed. The answer is very likely "It depends".

I just tried to apply for a 12-month multiple-entry tourist visa for China here in Sydney as an Australian citizen. I've had two previous double-entry Chinese visas.

But I was told I could only apply for a single- or double-entry visa this time too.

Not because of lack of previous Chinese visas, but for lack of documented itinerary. I showed a printout of a return flight and the first week of accommodation. I was told this was insufficient for a multiple entry visa. I was not told how much more would be needed. Perhaps the entire itinerary. Perhaps just one or two more? -:

Now these things may also depend on which passport you carry and in which country you are applying.

---

**Update**: When I picked up my visa I mentioned to the lady at the visa office how I tried to get a one-year multiple-entry visa and she told me that it requires **at least three flight and accommodation bookings**. I did not think to ask her if that meant three return flights or if any three flights, being either in or out might be sufficient.